# Let X be a non constant positive random variable such that E(X)=9. Then which of the following statements is correct

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let X be a non constant positive random variable such that E(X)=9. Then which of the following statements is correct

A) $E(\frac{1}{X+1})>0.1$ and $P(X \geq 10) \leq 0.9$
B) $E(\frac{1}{X+1})<0.1$ and $P(X \geq 10) \leq 0.9$
C) $E(\frac{1}{X+1})>0.1$ and $P(X \geq 10) > 0.9$
D) $E(\frac{1}{X+1})<0.1$ and $P(X \geq 10) > 0.9$

I am unable to understand how to proceed. Can someone please help me out

Comment: Do you know Jensen's and Markov's inequalities?

Comment: A) is correct. Use the fact that $\frac  1 {1+x}$ is a  convex fucntion.

Comment: got it! Thank you for the help

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/517535/119261.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markov's Inequality says that for a random variable $X$ with expected value $E(X)$, for any $a>0$, $$P(X\geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}.$$ Here we would obtain $P(X\geq10) \leq 9/10 = 0.9$, so it is either $(A)$ or $(B)$. How can you use Jensen's Inequality to get a bound on $E\left(\tfrac{1}{X+1}\right)$?